# Simpelest way to get a raw json response using retrofit and rxjava

Tags: json, gson, deserialization

Whats the simplest code i can use to start an asynchronous thread to fetch json data and then parse it on the UI thread in android using retrofit and rxjava?

I have searched this for two days and every solution so far gives me an error.
I basically want to replace all the old async tasks in my app with the newer retrofit and rxjava way of doing things.

```
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Response;
import rx.Subscriber;

PoloniexService.getInstance().getAllCoins()
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Response<ResponseBody>>() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Response<ResponseBody> responseBodyResponse) {

                }
            });
```

Something like this.. Except this gives me the error:
Cannot resolve method 'subscribe(anonymous rx.Subscriber<retrofit2.Response<okhttp3.ResponseBody>>)'